# Problem during development of string manipulation program

Tags: java, string

I have this problem where a string, sometimes, will repeat its end and I have to remove this repetition, returning only the main string. For example:

in: `sanduichuiche` out: `sanduiche`
in: `jabutiti` out: `jabuti`
in: `sol` out: `sol`

I'm using Java and the solution I came up with is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String linha;

    while ((linha = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String palavra = linha;
        palavra = palavra.trim()
                .replaceAll("\n","")
                .replaceAll("\t","");

        String subString;
        String subStringEncontrada = "";
        int palavraLength = palavra.length();

        for (int i = palavraLength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int diff = palavraLength - i;
            subString = palavra.substring(i, palavraLength);

            if (i-diff < 0) { break; }

            if (palavra.substring(i-diff,i).contains(subString)) {
                subStringEncontrada = subString;

            }
        }

        String resultado = palavra.substring( 0, palavraLength-subStringEncontrada.length()).trim();
        System.out.println(resultado);

    }
    out.close();
}
```

For some reason, when I post it to the code challenge, it says 2 of the tests failed, and I have run out of ideas about what can be wrong.

I appreciate if someone could help me out and say what I am missing on this code.

Comment: Does the code challenge state which tests failed?

Comment: Didn't try to debug your code but if you are familiar with regex you could use something like `result = line.replaceAll("(\\w+)\\1+$", "$1");`.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Unfortunately, they dont. Whic makes it harder to know what is wrong.

Comment: @Pshemo I was trying to avoid regex for this problem, but Ill give it a try

Comment: @FelipeGusmão: Hmm... one of the issues that may come up is how they interpret the repetitions. Should "watootoo" be turned into "watoo", "watooto", or "wato"? Aside from that, don't forget to test for empty or null strings.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I see what you mean. It always removes the bigest repeated substring, so, in this case, it would return "watoo", eliminating "too". Anymays, its very strange because this same chanlenge is on URI Online e there my code was accepted.... It makes no sense at all....

Comment: "It always removes the biggest repeated substring" then what should be result for `abaaaa`? If it is biggest substring then inside `aaaa` we have 2x `aa` so result would be `abaaaa` -> `abaa`. But maybe idea is to minimize *length of single repetition* and maximize amount of repetitions? In that case we should consider `aaaa` as 4x `a` making `abaaaa` -> `aba`. For such case we can use regex like `.replaceAll("(\\w+?)\\1+$", "$1")` to force `\w+` to match minimal amount of characters.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you're overcomplicating.
I wrote this version in a couple minutes, you can try and see if it works for your test cases.

```
private static String removeEndRepetition(final String str) {
   // We need to remove a possible duplicate part of a string, placed at its end.
   // This means the max duplicate length is str.length / 2
   for (int i = (int) Math.ceil(str.length() / 2.0); i < str.length(); i++) {
      final String possibleDuplicatePart = str.substring(i);
      final String precedingPart = str.substring(i - possibleDuplicatePart.length(), i);

      if (possibleDuplicatePart.equals(precedingPart)) {
         return str.substring(0, i);
      }
   }

   return str;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
   System.out.println(removeEndRepetition("sanduicheiche"));
   System.out.println(removeEndRepetition("jabutiti"));
   System.out.println(removeEndRepetition("sol"));
}
```

Which correctly prints

```
sanduiche
jabuti
sol
```

How does it work? Kinda debug with `sanduicheiche`:

```
possibleDuplicatePart   precedingPart
heiche                  anduic
eiche                   duich
iche                    iche           MATCH!
```

Comment: pretty clever indeed

Comment: I have used your code but the same exact tests failed and they dont show what input was used. The input description is: "There will be many teste cases. Each one is composed by one word of 30 characters, maximum. The output is just the word after correction

Comment: @FelipeGusmão can you link me the test?

Comment: @LppEdd https://web.digitalinnovation.one/coding/praticando-programacao-em-java/algorithm/entrevista-embaracosa?back=/track/inter-java-developer Its in portuguese. I hope. its not a problem.

Comment: @FelipeGusmão it's the site that screws up... It's a bit of a mess. I receive "2 / 2 Testes de abertos tiveram sucesso. Clique em "ENTREGAR DESAFIO" para executar todos os testes e finalizar esse desafio." What does that mean?

Comment: @FelipeGusmão I lost two hearts hahahaha

Comment: @LppEdd And I have run out of hearts already hahahaha. "testes abertos tiveram sucesso" means "you succeded on the open tests". this open tests show the input and output. " ENTREGAR DESAFIO para executar todos os testes e finalizar esse desafio" means "DELIVER CHALENGE to execute all of the tests and conclude this chalenge".

Comment: @FelipeGusmão Thanks! 4/7 are done. But how do I see the others if they're locked?

Comment: @LppEdd They do not show how the closed tests are done, and that sucks, because I have no idea what the problem is...

Comment: I get the same 4/7 done. I think they dont show, so nobody can cheat on the chalenge

Comment: @FelipeGusmão have no idea then, sorry. Although honestly I think the solution is right, it's probably how we "read" those lines/words.

Comment: @LppEdd I think so too. Anyway, thank you very much for your code and time, man. I apreciate it. I'm gonna lose some more hearts now hahaha

Comment: @FelipeGusmão no problem. Let me know if you end up having 7/7 tests passed.